# Prestashop - where is the code to search products by manufacturer name?

Tags: php, sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a shop on Prestashop 1.7 with books. Some of them have two authors. Authors are stored as a manufacturers. I made a plugin to allow user to assign more than one manufacturer to single product, but now I must fix products search to use my custom table of assignments in search process. The problem is that I can't find where is the sql code which is looking for manufacturer name. I already spend whole day for this without results. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep digging: it is not so easy as I thought... Prestashop keeps keywords in table called search_word which is connected by id_word with table search_index where all words are assigned to id_product, so now my job is to assign manufacturer name as a search words to updated product - sounds complicated, but it shouldn't be so hard

Answer (score 1):

Look into the file classes/Search.php method find. In my case, it is line 331. you need to modify this query to change a search approach

Comment: I just found it, but still don't know where is something like "where manufacturer.name like '%blabla%'"

Comment: @Joint And you won't find this. By default, product can have only one manufacturer which id is in table product field id_manufacturer. So we need just bind the product table with the manufacturer table by this id to get all manufacturer info. In your case, you have modified a logic so now you need to modify the query and add your own JOIN table with your conditions

Comment: Yes, I know, but there must be somewhere a code looking for manufacturer name to get his id. Instead how it knows which id_manufacturer to find?

Comment: oh... it is not so easy as I though... Prestashop keeps keywords in table called search_word connected by id_word with table search_index where all words are assigned to id_product, so now my job is to assign manufacturer name as a search words to updated product - sounds complicated, but it shouldn't

Comment: I think, at first, you need to add information about your manufacturers during indexation in the method getProductsToIndex. You can combine all your manufacturers' name in one string and then put it in mname field. Later everything will be split by words and all necessary records will be added to tables with indexes and all should work correct